# Obtener ultima fecha de modificacion de carpeta con Batch

Tags: batch

tengo un batch que ejecuta un programa, pero la unica forma de saber si tuvo algun error este programa es accediendo a la carpeta de log de errores de ese programa y ver si se creo un nuevo archivo con un error.
Necesito obtener la fecha y hora de modificación de la carpeta que contiene esos errores para compararla con la fecha y hora de antes de abrir el programa, y saber si se creo un nuevo error o si se ejecuto correctamente, tengo una idea de como hacerlo pero no conozco del todo Batch y no he encontrado algo similar en internet.

Anexo el codigo (se que esta mal la parte del IF, solo es por poner un ejemplo)

```
@echo off
IF EXIST "c:\Facturas2.txt" (
    REM Abres DTW
    cd "C:\Program Files\SAP\Data Transfer Workbench"


    REM obtener fecha actual
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
    set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
    set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

    set "fullstamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%%Sec%"


    REM Ejecutas DTW con la ruta al archivo XML a cargar
    DTW -s C:\Facturas2.xml

    if "Fecha de modificacion de carpeta C:\error files con formato YYYYMMDDHHMinSec" es mayor o igual a %fullstamp%
            
        REN c:\Facturas2.txt errorFacturas2.txt
        exit /b

    Else 
    MOVE c:\Facturas2.txt c:\Historico
    
)
```

Comment: Saludos. ¿Has intentado usando `date -r` en tu carpeta o `stat`?

Comment: Hola, no he intentado eso, me puedes dar un ejemplo de como se usa ese comando, para poder poner la fecha en una variable o algo y compararla en el if. PD Gracias por la ayuda